# Разработка формы регистрации

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток! Значит пишу "регистрацию пользователя"(для себя, учусь). Вот код

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$pol = $_REQUEST['pol'];
$region = $_REQUEST['region'];
$other = $_REQUEST['other'];

$mysql_insert = "INSERT INTO user (name,pass,email,pol,region,other)".
"VALUES('{$name}','{$pass}'{$email}',{$pol}',{$region}',{$other}');";
mysql_query($mysql_insert) or die ("<p>Ошибка вставки ".mysql_error());
echo 'Пользователь добавлен в список!';
?>
<br>
<br>
<a href="index.php">Вернуться в меню</a>
```

А когда ввожу все поля и жму кнопку "регистрировать" появляется ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to
> your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near
> '123',123',12312',asdas')' at line 1

Comment: Ну и формулировка вопроса :) Да и тег ясности не добавляет (переметил на более подходящие). Даже плюсану! :)

Comment: Рег**и**страция  
А ошибка в кавычках и запятых! Проверьте Ваш запрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так у вас кавычки пропущены, в сообщении об ошибке это же явно показано!

Comment: Ох уж эти кавычки, запятые...Спасибо огромное!